# How difficult are lattice algorithms for low-dimensional lattices?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-hard, cryptography, lattices

Most lattice problems, such as the shortest vector problem, the closest vector problem, shortest basis problem, etc, are NP-hard and thus conjectured to be worst-case exponential time in the rank of the lattice.

However, suppose the rank is determined in advance, and is particularly low, like 2D and 3D. Then, the only source of variability is the magnitude of the values of the vector coefficients. **How do things scale there?**

To be precise, here is what I am looking for:

1. We have a 2D or 3D lattice, represented as a basis of vectors which have integer coordinates.
2. These vectors could have coordinate values in e.g. the trillions or so, but the dimension is low and determined in advance.
3. I want to compute an approximate LLL reduced basis. How does this scale with the basis vector coefficients?
4. I want to compute the *true* shortest basis. How does this scale with the basis vector coefficients?
5. I want to compute the *true* shortest vector in the lattice. How does this scale with the basis vector coefficients?

And so on. I am particularly interested in how difficult or easy it is to compute true shortest vectors for low-rank lattices.

From playing around with it, it seems like most routines do successfully manage to compute things like shortest vectors for low-dimensional lattices pretty easily, even for vectors with values in the trillions. Thus, it seems that most of the hardness results from higher-dimensional lattices, which most lattice-based cryptosystems use. However, I could use some clarification on this and where the line is drawn.